# Outdenting of content of removed block

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm writing a Roslyn Diagnostic with Code Fix. If there's a try block with one empty catch block, i want to provide the option to remove the catch block and replace the try block with its content. My problem is the outdenting of the content of the try block. I tried using the Formatter, but the lines are still indentend one level too much. Here's my code:

```
private async Task<Document> RemoveTryCatchBlockAsync(Document document, TryStatementSyntax tryBlock, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var oldRoot = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
    var newRoot = oldRoot.ReplaceNode(tryBlock, tryBlock.Block.ChildNodes());
    Formatter.Format(newRoot, MSBuildWorkspace.Create());

    // Return document with transformed tree. 
    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roslyn is very immutable, your `Formatter` won't be changing the original node but instead return you a new one that is formatted.

Instead, try this:

```
var formattedRoot = Formatter.Format(newRoot, MSBuildWorkspace.Create());
return document.WithSyntaxRoot(formattedRoot);
```